# Delphi + iOSでSafari起動方法？

Tags: ios, delphi

Delphi で記述されたプログラム上を、 iOSの上で実行する際に、Safariを起動したいです。どうしたらこれを実現できますでしょうか。

Comment: どのような動作を期待しておられるのでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

http://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=6952

```
uses FMX.Helpers.iOS, Macapi.Helpers;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  URL = 'http://www.google.com/';
begin
  SharedApplication.openURL(StrToNSUrl(URL));
end;
```